# Vim-like браузеры

Tags: vim, поиск-программ

Подскажите хороший браузер, наподобие `vim` - хотел установить расшиерение для `firefox`, но `vimperator` уже устарел, да и ф-ционал его не ровня vim. Очень уж полюбился `vim`, настолько, что стало очень не удобно пользоваться браузером, особенно что касается печати - вечно тянет перейти в коммандный режим и т.п.

Comment: Для FF есть еще [vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium). Но он для навигации больше подходит по странице/вкладкам.

Comment: На странице Vimperator есть список [**альтернатив**](https://github.com/vimperator/vimperator-labs#end-of-life-and-alternatives). Спасибо.

Comment: Я уже писал, что `vimperator` не подходит также из-за того, что, по-сути, поддерживает только скроллинг, ну и выделение еще. Хочется браузер более похожий на vim

Answer (score 0):

Долгое время использовал [qutebrowser](https://www.qutebrowser.org/index.html). Там все можно неплохо настроить под себя.